# Programmatically add @Input to Component through Attribute Directive

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-directive

I want to create a directive which shall automatically add some properties to the host component (ion-input) depending on some passed properties.

In HTML it should look like this:

```
<ion-input myDirective [myProperties]="attr.paras" [(ngModel)]="attr.value"></ion-input>
```

Through the directive I want to add some properties like min, max, minlength and maxlength. The component then should look like this:

```
<ion-input myDirective [myProperties]="attr.paras" [(ngModel)]="attr.value" [min]="1" [max]="100"></ion-input>
```

Because of validation the added attributes should be recognized with @Input in other directives. How can I achieve this?

If I do something like

```
this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('min', this.min);
```

The validation directives (using @Input) will not recognize this attribute.

> **Edit:** Nobody knows a solution for this problem? If I create a component instead, the ionic components will not work correctly, because of the wrapping tag.

Thanks,

Thilo